# Convert date string (EST) to Java Date (UTC)

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, data-conversion

I need some advice on this java method.  The intent of this method is to take a string that represents a date - this string was created from a date in the EST time zone - and convert it to a java Date object in the UTC time zone.

```
private Date buildValidationDate(String dateString) throws ParseException {
    System.out.println("dateString " + dateString);

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyy hh:mm a");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));  
    dateFormat.setLenient(true);
    Date dt = dateFormat.parse(dateString);

    System.out.println("dt " + dt);

    return dt;
}
```

the problem I'm seeing is the value of dt seems to be off.  For instance, if dateString is '10/16/2012 12:06 PM' - I'm expecting the value of dt (in UTC) to be something like 'Tuesday, October 16, 2012 4:06 PM'.  Instead the value of dt is 'Tue Oct 16 07:06:00 CDT 2012'.  This does not seem to be the correct UTC time.

I appreciate any advice, I'm sorry if this seems to be an easy question I have a lot of trouble with Java dates.  I'm not sure if I'm coding something incorrectly or if there is something wrong with my methodology.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your date is getting converted right**. Its just printing value in your default timezone format as `java.util.Date` is timezone independent. If you want timezone specific handling, please use `java.util.Calendar`.

Comment: Even better: Use the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 6):

As the [correct accepted answer by Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12919211/642706) says, your `Date` actually *is* in UTC but its `toString` method confusingly applies the current default time zone while generating the string.

## ISO 8601

Avoid such formats as `10/16/2012 12:06 PM` for date-time values. When serializing to text, use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats defined as a standard for this very purpose.

## java.time

> I'm sorry if this seems to be an easy question I have a lot of trouble with Java dates

It's not you; it's the classes. The old legacy date-time classes were a valiant industry-leading effort at handling date-time. But they proved to be ill-conceived, poorly-designed, very confusing, and troublesome. Now supplanted by the java.time classes – a *gigantic* improvement.

Avoid this troublesome old `java.util.Date` class entirely. Instead use `Instant` in its place.

### `Instant`

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

Get the current moment.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

You can convert a Date to its modern replacement by calling one of the new conversion methods added to the old date-time classes. Just call toInstant, quite easy.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant();
```

The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when generating strings. Just call `toString` to get a clear representation of the value within the object.

```
String output = instant.toString();
```

> 2016-12-23T01:33:09.731Z

### Parsing

To parse your input string, define a formatting pattern to match. The pattern codes are similar to that of `SimpleDateFormat` but not exactly the same. So be sure to study the doc carefully.

```
String input = "10/16/2012 12:06 PM" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu hh:mm a" );
```

Your input lacks any clue about offset-from-UTC or time zone. So we must parse as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). Lacking any offset or zone, a `LocalDateTime` is only a vague idea about possible moments but does *not* represent a point on the timeline.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

> ldt.toString(): 2012-10-16T12:06

The Question claims this was meant for “EST time zone”. So we need to apply a time zone, a `ZoneId`, to our `LocalDateTime` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

Perhaps by `EST` you meant the time zones used across much of the east coast of the United States and Canada. I will arbitrarily choose `America/New_York`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2012-10-16T12:06-04:00[America/New_York]

To get to UTC, simply extract a `Instant`. You can think of this conceptually as:

> ZonedDateTime = ( Instant + ZoneId )

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
```

> instant.toString(): 2012-10-16T16:06:00Z