# convert date and time in any timezone to UTC zone

Tags: java, date, timezone, simpledateformat

- this is my date " 15-05-2014 00:00:00 "
- how to convert IST to UTC i.e( to 14-05-2014 18:30:00)
- based on from timezone  to UTC timezone.

my code is

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");

formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));  //here set timezone

System.out.println(formatter.format(date));  
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));  //static UTC timezone

System.out.println(formatter.format(date));  
String str = formatter.format(date);
Date date1  = formatter.parse(str);
System.out.println(date1.toString());
```

- if user enter same date from any zone then will get UTC time(ex: from Australia then 15-05-2014 00:00:00 to 14-05-2014 16:00:00)
- please any suggestions.

Comment: when you print it will always be in the local timezone irrespective of IST or EST. so is your assignment related to only printing or you want to use that value further

Comment: thanks for replay, different timezone users entered From and To dates, i want convert that date values and use for further calculations.i did not printing to this values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert date string (EST) to Java Date (UTC)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919067/convert-date-string-est-to-java-date-utc)

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**You cannot "convert that date values" to other timezones or UTC.** The type `java.util.Date` does not have any internal timezone state and only refers to UTC by spec in a way which cannot be changed by user (just counting the milliseconds since UNIX epoch in UTC timezone leaving aside leapseconds).

**But you can convert the formatted String-representation of a `java.util.Date` to another timezone.** I prefer to use two different formatters, one per timezone (and pattern). I also prefer to use "Asia/Kolkata" in your case because then it will universally works (IST could also be "Israel Standard Time" which will be interpreted differently in Israel):

```
DateFormat formatterIST = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
formatterIST.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata")); // better than using IST
Date date = formatterIST.parse("15-05-2014 00:00:00");
System.out.println(formatterIST.format(date)); // output: 15-05-2014 00:00:00

DateFormat formatterUTC = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
formatterUTC.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); // UTC timezone
System.out.println(formatterUTC.format(date)); // output: 14-05-2014 18:30:00

// output in system timezone using pattern "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"
System.out.println(date.toString()); // output in my timezone: Wed May 14 20:30:00 CEST 2014
```

Answer (score 14):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "15-05-2014 00:00:00" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu HH:mm:ss" ) 
)
.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) )
.toInstant()
```

## java.time

The [Answer by Meno Hochschild](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24262202/642706) is correct but shows classes that are now outdated.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu HH:mm:ss" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "15-05-2014 00:00:00" , f ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2014-05-15T00:00

Apparently you are certain that string represents a moment in India time. Tip: You should have included the zone or offset in that string. Even better, use standard ISO 8601 formats.

Assign the India time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2014-05-15T00:00+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

To see the same moment, the same point on the timeline, through the wall-clock time of UTC, extract an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2014-05-14T18:30:00Z

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

With a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complying with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings or java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).