# Android - Getting different UTC time

Tags: android, date, utc

I have two methods for get UTC date time.

**method:1) get current UTC**

```
 public static String getUTCdatetimeAsString()
{


    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd- HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    final String utcTime = sdf.format(new Date());
    Log.e("utcTime : " ,""+ utcTime);
    return utcTime;
}
```

which print below Log

```
utcTime : 2018-07-12- 12:37:09
```

**method:2) select date from calendar and get UTC**

```
public static String dateUTCToLocal() {

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        Date value = formatter.parse("12/7/2018 06:07:09");

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd- HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        return format.format(value);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

which print below Log

```
2018-07-12- 11:37:09
```

**Problem :** getting different UTC date (1 hour different )not understand why i tried many solutions but not getting perfect result, any help appreciate thanks in advance.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes. They are long outdated, and the latter in particular notoriously troublesome. You’re far from the first having problems with it. Instead you may add [the ThreeTenABP library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It’s so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Was method 2 supposed to convert 12/7/2018 06:07:09 from UTC to local time or from local time to UTC?

Comment: Did you search thoroughly enough before asking? This question has been asked and answered many times already, so please do. Possible duplicate of [convert date and time in any timezone to UTC zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240896/convert-date-and-time-in-any-timezone-to-utc-zone).

Answer (score 1):

Try this format ..

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd- HH:mm:ss a", Locale.US);
```

it show time into am pm wise.

Comment: i use this "HH:mm:ss a" but getting this kind of response : 1)2018-07-12- 12:41:19 PM
2)2018-07-12- 11:41:19 AM

Comment: check time are passing both method it same.

Answer (score 0):

The line "format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());" sets the timezone you are currently in while "sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));" sets the timezone to "UTC". You should stick with the second line if you want to get UTC-time