# How to convert XML timestamp with timezone to UTC?

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, utc, date-conversion

I have stored in a `String` type variable `my_date` a value retrieved from an XML file.

The `my_date` is in GMT and has a timezone offset that needs to be considered for the UTC conersion.

I would like to convert it (another `String`) but in UTC format without the timezone - for example:

```
String my_date = "2020-02-16T20:40:55.000+01:00"
//Convertion
String my_date_utc = "2020-02-16 21:40:55.000"
```

Comment: Hope this answer helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/24262202/2553521

Answer (score 2):

Parse as a [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object. Adjust the offset to UTC, producing a second `OffsetDateTime` object.

```
OffsetDateTime
.parse
(
    "2020-02-16T20:40:55.000+01:00"
)
.withOffsetSameInstant
(
    ZoneOffset.UTC
)
```

Understand that date-time objects are *not* `String` objects. They parse and generate strings as inputs and outputs.

Search Stack Overflow to learn about producing strings in various formats using `DateTimeFormatter`. That has been covered many hundreds of times already.

Comment: [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) doesn't have a `withOffset()` method, so you should change that to [`withOffsetSameInstant()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#withOffsetSameInstant-java.time.ZoneOffset-), and since the desired result is without time zone, you should call [`toLocalDateTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toLocalDateTime--) after that, rather than rely on the formatter to not output the time zone.

Comment: @Andreas (A) Thanks for the correction on my error with method name. Now fixed. (B) I disagree about using `LocalDateTime`. Stripping away vital context information (the offset) simply for reporting where that context can be assumed by the person reading is  needlessly extreme. Reporting a value to the user as text is a job separate from managing that value internally. That reporting job is exactly the purpose of `DateTimeFormatter`.