# TimeZone Date Conversion [Convert a Date object to a specified timeZone Date Object]

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, timezone, java.util.date

```
My approach :
// initailize date object
Date date = new Date();
// get time zone
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Asia/Dubai");

// create zonedDateTime object
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), zoneId);

// instant of zonedDateTime
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();

// convert instant to specified zone
instant.atZone(zoneId);

// Get Local Date Time Object
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant,zoneId);

//Convert it back to Date Object
Date dateFinal = java.util.Date.from(Instant.from(ldt.atZone(zoneId)));
```

Can anyone help me with conversion of timeZone Date object in Java 8
`Date date = Fri Mar 31 16:10:13 IST`.
Now I need to convert this Date to any given timeZone Date object

Desired result:

> `Date resultDate = Fri Mar 31 14:40:13 GST`

Basically here I used (Asia/Dubai) Time Zone

But my result is: `2023-03-31T16:10:13.854+0530`. I am getting the result in IST only. It’s not getting converted to (Asia/Dubai).

I have mentioned all the ways I have tried.

Comment: `Date` does not contain a timezone. It represents a point in time, like `Instant`. This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). `date` and `dateFinal` will always be the same. How about using `zdt` as your final result?

Comment: Also, don't use mix the old and new APIs.  `Date` is old, and you don't need it in most cases anymore.  Use only the `java.time.*` types.

Comment: Since a `Date` with a specified time zone is impossible, don’t you simply want `ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId)`?

Comment: *But my result is: `2023-03-31T16:10:13.854+0530`.* I didn’t get that exactly. An old-fashioned `Date` did not print in that format. So how exactly did you get that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert date string (EST) to Java Date (UTC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919067/convert-date-string-est-to-java-date-utc)

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Core Concept: *`java.util.Date` does **not** have a time zone*. The `Date#toString` method lies to you.

If handed a legacy `java.util.Date` object, immediately convert to `java.time.Instant`.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

Then apply your desired time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Dubai" ) ) ;
```

## Use only *java.time*

Your date-time handling should involve **only the *java.time* classes**.

The date-time classes outside that package are now legacy, terribly flawed in poor design. The legacy classes were supplanted by *java.time* in JSR 310, implemented in Java 8+.

You said:

```java
// initailize date object
Date date = new Date();
```

Did you mean `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`? Both are legacy.

- The first was replaced by `java.time.Instant`. Both the legacy and modern classes represent a moment as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.
- The second was replaced by `java.time.LocalDate`. The legacy class *pretends* to represent a date-only, but because of faulty design it actually contains a time-of-day and an assumption of an offset of zero. In contrast, the modern class truly represents a date-only, without time-of-day, and without time zone or offset.

Instead use this code:

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment as seen in UTC (zero offset).
```

You said:

```java
// get time zone
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Asia/Dubai");
```

Good. A `ZoneId` is the modern way to represent a time zone. And `Asia/Dubai`, in `Continent/Region` is the correct naming for [real time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

You said:

```java
// create zonedDateTime object
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), zoneId);
```

Using our `Instant` object seen above, use this code:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( zoneId ) ;
```

Both `instant` & `zdt` here represent the same simultaneous moment, the same point on the timeline. But the latter is viewed through the wall-clock time used by people in a particular region.

You said:

```java
// instant of zonedDateTime
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
```

Yes, you can extract an `Instant` from a `ZonedDateTime`. But this code in unnecessary here as we already instantiate a `Instant` object to capture the current moment.

You said:

```java
// convert instant to specified zone
instant.atZone(zoneId);
```

The problem here is that an `Instant` object, like all the *java.time* objects, is [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). You can alter (“mutate”) the content of an `Instant` object after its creation. That moment is frozen forever.

Furthermore, calling `Instant#atZone` returns a fresh new `ZonedDateTime` object. We saw just that in our code earlier above. Your code shown above ignores the new `ZonedDateTime` object returned by `atZone`.

You said:

```java
// Get Local Date Time Object
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant,zoneId);
```

Two problem here:

- You can more easily obtain a `LocalDateTime` from the `ZonedDateTime` instantiated above. `LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime() ;`
- You may not be aware that in creating the `LocalDateTime`, you are **discarding valuable information**: the time zone. So you are left with merely a date and a time-of-day. But such a value is inherently ambiguous. For example, if noon on January 23 this year, we do not know if you meant in noon in Tokyo Japan, noon in Toulouse France, or noon in Toledo Ohio US — three very different moments several hours apart.

Tip: If you do not yet fully grok date-time handling, avoid using `LocalDateTime`. In most business situations, we generally care about a moment, a specific point on the timeline. `LocalDateTime` does not fit that case.

You said:

```java
//Convert it back to Date Object
Date dateFinal = java.util.Date.from(Instant.from(ldt.atZone(zoneId)));
```

Two problems here:

- You can more easily write `java.util.Date.from( instant )` as we already have an `Instant` in hand. Or, if we had just the `ZonedDateTime` seen above, `java.util.Date.from( zdt.toInstant() )`.
- You would usually never write this in new code. Convert to the legacy code only where necessary to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*. Otherwise, avoid both `Date` classes like the plague. Ditto for `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, etc.

Your title asks:

> [Convert a Date object to a specified timeZone Date Object]

I do not understand what you mean. The `java.util.Date` class represents a moment in UTC. It has no time zone.

(Actually there *is* a time zone buried with its code, but this code is practically irrelevant, and represents another of those terrible design decisions found in the legacy date-time classes.)

You said:

> timeZone Date object in JAVA 8 Date date = Fri Mar 31 16:10:13 IST

Do not be fooled by the `java.util.Date#toString` method. That method unfortunately injects the JVM’s current default time zone while generating text. While well-intentioned, this creates the false illusion that `Date` includes a time zone in its meaning when in fact it is "in UTC" (has an offset from UTC of zero).