# Different date in local and the server java date time

Tags: java, date, datetime, gregorian-calendar, xmlgregoriancalendar

When I run below code which converts a xml date to java date, it prints different value(CST) in local vs different value(UTC) in the server running the same code, what could be reason for it? How can I always print this date in CST format which I am getting in my local.
I can't use latest java date API and have to use XML based date.

```
    import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConstants;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConstants;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Demo {
    public static final TimeZone TIMEZONE = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago");

    public static Date convertDate(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            if (value.getXMLSchemaType() == DatatypeConstants.DATE) {
                return value.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
            } else {
                return value.toGregorianCalendar(TIMEZONE, null, null).getTime();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Parse the XML date string into XMLGregorianCalendar
            XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2024-02-09T01:57:33.240-06:00");
            // Convert XMLGregorianCalendar to Date
            Date date = convertDate(xmlDate);
            // Print the result
            System.out.println("Date: " + date);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Date: Fri Feb 09 01:57:33 CST 2024 - **local output(Intellij - my mac time zone CST)**

Date: Fri Feb 09 07:57:33 UTC 2024 - **server output(https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler)**

**I need to store the date in america/chicago timezone irrespective of the user location  and I have no control over the database query**

Comment: The way you print the result will use the timezone set in the vm that runs it. Why are you starting with an xml date?

Comment: I'd be careful with using `Date#toString` as it's going to make use of local settings to print a human readable representation of the date.  Instead, make use of a suitable date formatter whose configuration you can control.

Comment: `OffsetDateTime.parse("2024-02-09T01:57:33.240-06:00").atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"));` giving *2024-02-09T01:57:33.240-06:00[America/Chicago]* is the sort of thing you *should* be doing. 'CST' is not really a proper timezone (ambiguous)

Comment: I'd also recommend creating a disconnect between the client and server, so that any date/time value retrieved from the sever can more easily be reasoned with based on the client's desired representation - ie, store the values in UTC on the server and then allow the clients to represent that value based on their locale

Comment: btw...GMT==UTC!  ..and let me guess: CST is your local (mac) timezone!? ;) (UTC is the "best practice" server TZ)

Comment: CST is my local machine as well as I need to store in CST time zone in db running on a vm

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/time-zones-java-web-application/

Comment: [All about java.util.Date](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/)

Comment: You jjdoodle link does not show what I had expected nor anything relevant to the question.

Comment: *How can I always print this date in CST format ...* *the function in my original question convertDate(XMLGregorianCalendar value) have to return a java.util.date* You are asking the impossible. A java.util.Date cannot hold a time zone. See for example [Convert date string (EST) to Java Date (UTC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919067/convert-date-string-est-to-java-date-utc). Does that question answer yours?

Comment: Since you wanted to offer a bounty on your question (which is nice and probably a good idea), for the best value back from your bounty I suggest that you improve and clarify the question the best you can. I seem to understand from your comments that your end goal is to save the date (with or without time) to your database in -- by CST, do you mean either America/Winnipeg or America/Chicago time zone? (Other interpretations of the abbreviation exist.) Make this clear in your question and also, as @g00se wisely asked, tell us your brand of RDBMS and your column type. So we may help you better.

Comment: Also are you getting `XMLGregorianCalendar` objects without second of minute?Without time at all? What should happen if you do? Asking because in your code you are checking `value.getXMLSchemaType() == DatatypeConstants.DATE`.

Comment: I want to store in america/chicago timezone, I am getting a UTC time with offset as  as input, I want to convert it to america/chicago timezone and store in db2 database

Comment: @Anonymous I have IBM db2 database, and I need to always store in america/chicago timezone,

Answer (score 5):

### Use `timestamp with time zone` in UTC in your database

For a point in time in your database use UTC, universal time. And to make sure that your database knows that it is in UTC, use `timestamp with time zone` data type.

You may think that storing time in your local time zone, America/Chicago, is simpler and more suited to your purpose. Think again. While your app is designed for that time zone at the moment, who can guarantee that it won’t be used by users in other locations of the US at some point in the future? That the component you’re coding won’t be reused in some other program some other time? If this is for a school project to be thrown out after exams, a school project is a very good place to train best practices. Best practice here is to store UTC time.

If furthermore using `timestamp` without time zone or `datetime` in the database, a possibly minor problem is that times in America/Chicago time zone are occasionally ambiguous. Every year in the beginning of November summer time (DST) ends and the clocks are turned an hour back. Last 5 November at 2 AM, for example, clocks were turned back to 1 even though it had already been 1 AM an hour earlier. So when you retrieve a time between 1 and 2 in the night from the database, you have no way of knowing whether summer time (CDT) or standard time (CST) was intended. Also sorting such times is bound to mix them between each other. UTC does not use summer time, hence hasn’t got this problem.

Different RDBMSs have different notions of `timestamp with time zone`. Your DB2 stores a UTC offset with the timestamp. Others store time in UTC and when necessary convert to and from some local time zone on storing and retrieving, really only giving us "timestamp with UTC time zone", which is fine too. I suggest you always store offset 0 (zero). Yet a few allow you to store a time zone ID such as `America/Chicago`. Use `Etc/UTC` here. In all cases the type is fine for your purpose.

### java.time

I understand that your requirement to store time in America/Chicago time zone is fixed. So store an `OffsetDateTime` with the correct UTC offset (-6 or -5 hours) into your DB2 `timestamp with time zone` column. If `timestamp` without time zone (or `datetime` in other RDBMSs) is dictated from others, store a `LocalDateTime`. First let’s get the conversion from `XMLGregorianCalendar` right:

```
public static final ZoneId ZONE_ID = ZoneId.of("America/Chicago");

/**
 * For this code example I am assuming that a date without time is stored as the start of day
 * and a date with time requires a UTC offset.
 * In both cases I am converting to America/Chicago time zone.
 */
public static OffsetDateTime convertXmlgcToOdt(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
    if (value.getHour() == DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED
            && value.getMinute() == DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED
            && value.getSecond() == DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED
            && value.getFractionalSecond() == null) { // Date only
        return value.toGregorianCalendar()
                .toZonedDateTime()
                .toLocalDate()
                .atStartOfDay(ZONE_ID)
                .toOffsetDateTime();
    } else { // date and time
        if (value.getTimezone() == DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("value must have UTC offset (\"timezone\")");
        }
        return value.toGregorianCalendar()
                .toZonedDateTime()
                .withZoneSameInstant(ZONE_ID)
                .toOffsetDateTime();
    }
}
```

Caveat: My conversion has milliseconds precision even though both `XMLGregorianCalendar` and `OffsetDateTime` have finer precision. If you need to preserve any finer precision than milliseconds from XML, I suggest:

```
        OffsetDateTime converted = OffsetDateTime.parse(value.toString());
        return converted.atZoneSameInstant(ZONE_ID)
                .toOffsetDateTime();
```

Let’s try the conversion method out:

```
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendar("2024-02-09T01:57:33.240-06:00");
    System.out.println(convertXmlgcToOdt(xmlDate));
    xmlDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendar("2024-02-09");
    System.out.println(convertXmlgcToOdt(xmlDate));
```

Output:

> ```
> 2024-02-09T01:57:33.240-06:00
> 2024-02-09T00:00-06:00
> ```

If instead you need to convert to `LocalDateTime`, replace each of the two lines calling `toOffsetDeteTime()` with `.toLocalDateTime();`.

To store in your database use something like the following, assuming you are using JDBC:

```
    OffsetDateTime odt = convertXmlgcToOdt(xmlDate);
    PreparedStatement pStmt = yourDatabaseConnection
            .prepareStatement("insert into your_table(your_tstz_column) values(?);");
    pStmt.setObject(1, odt);
    pStmt.executeUpdate();
```

If using `timestamp wthout time zone` and therefore `LocalDateTime`, just pass your `LocalDateTime` to `setObject()` in exactly the same way.

### For really old Java versions

If using Java 6 or 7, use the backport of java.time named ThreeTen Backport, link at the bottom. In this case you can’t directly pass the java.time objects to your `PreparedStatement`. One option is to convert to an old-fashioned `java.sql.Timestamp` and pass it to `PreparedStatement.setTimestmap()`. The `Timestamp` class was a true hack on top of the already poorly designed `Date` class. Another optoin is to format into strings that you pass to `PreparedStatement.setString()`. If using Java 5, use Joda-Time in a similar manner.

### Control the time zone via the database session

If for some reason I can’t guess you are forced to use one of the problematic and outdated `Date` classes, use the conversion you already have. Configure your database session to use America/Chicago time zone. I don’t understand the logic in this configuration belonging to the session, to me it rather belongs to the database column; but most SQL databases offer it as a setting on the session. Search for how it’s done with your brand of database engine/RDBMS. I include a link for DB2 below to get you started. The DB2 “session time zone” is a mere offset from UTC, so when dealing with times in both standard time and summer time, you will need to set it for each value stored.

**Or via the JVM default time zone:** The really dirty solution is to set the default time zone of your JVM independent of the server OS time zone. Beware that this will affect the entire Java program and may have unwanted effects in other parts of it. I expect it to control the time zone used to converting `Date` to either of the database `timestamp` data types, though (I have not tested).

Either start your server program with a command line option for the purpose, like for example:

```
java -Duser.timezone=America/Chicago YourApp
```

Or set the property from within your code, before doing any date and time work:

```
    System.setProperty("user.timezone", "America/Chicago");
```

### If all else fails, tell a lie

If none of the above is viable in your setup, you need a way to compensate for the fact that your server JVM and your database disagree about time zone and the `Date` is therefore converted incorrectly when stored. The trick that I think you used in your own answer seems to work, only please be aware that we are doing a *deliberately incorrect conversion* to compensate for the opposite incorrect conversion taking place out of our control when storing the `Date`. If that were me, I would want to make this very clear in the code, or anyone reading it in the future may be severely confused and may also try to “correct” what they may take to be an unintentional error. You can use your own conversion or mine or mix them somehow. Here’s mine:

```
/**
 * Convert to America/Chicago time zone
 * and then convert further to a {@code Date} that when interpreted
 * in the default time zone of the JVM
 * has the same date and time of day (wall-clock time)
 * no matter if this makes the point in time wrong.
 * We are doing a <em>deliberately incorrect conversion</em> to compensate
 * for the opposite incorrect conversion taking place out of our control when
 * storing the {@code Date}.
 * That incorrect conversion happens because the JVM and the database
 * disagree about time zone:
 * the JVM uses UTC (GMT), but the database column must be in America/Chicago time zone.
 */
public static Date convertDate(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        ZonedDateTime dateTimeWithDeliberatelyWrongTimeZone;
        if (value.getHour() == DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED
                && value.getMinute() == DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED
                && value.getSecond() == DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED
                && value.getFractionalSecond() == null) { // Date only
            dateTimeWithDeliberatelyWrongTimeZone = value.toGregorianCalendar()
                    .toZonedDateTime()
                    .toLocalDate()
                    .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        } else { // date and time
            if (value.getTimezone() == DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED) { // No UTC offset
                // In this case use UTC as default
                dateTimeWithDeliberatelyWrongTimeZone = value
                        .toGregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC), null, null)
                        .toZonedDateTime()
                        .withZoneSameInstant(ZONE_ID)
                        // Preserve date and time of day
                        // when converting to default time zone
                        .withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.systemDefault());
            } else {
                dateTimeWithDeliberatelyWrongTimeZone = value.toGregorianCalendar()
                        .toZonedDateTime()
                        .withZoneSameInstant(ZONE_ID)
                        // Preserve date and time of day
                        // when converting to default time zone
                        .withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.systemDefault());
            }
        }
        return Date.from(dateTimeWithDeliberatelyWrongTimeZone.toInstant());
    }
}
```

Converting the same two `XMLGregorianCalendar` objects as before in UTC time zone gives the following results:

> ```
> Fri Feb 09 01:57:33 UTC 2024
> Fri Feb 09 00:00:00 UTC 2024
> ```

You see that the `Date` objects are printed in UTC. Since the times are as expected, this means that the `Date`s are 6 hours off from CST, so incorrect as they should. The date and the times printed are also the ones that are stored to the database, which is what you wanted.

The case where we pass no offset in the `XMLGregorianCalendar`:

```
    xmlDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendar("2024-02-09T01:57:33.240");
```

> ```
> Thu Feb 08 19:57:33 UTC 2024
> ```

The date and time have been converted from UTC to CST so the CST date and time will be saved to the database. This time too the `Date` object is really 6 hours off.

When running the same three examples on a JVM with America/Chicago as default time zone (as on your local computer), the conversion is actually correct, which is also what we want because then there is no time zone conflict between local JVM and database:

> ```
> Fri Feb 09 01:57:33 CST 2024
> Fri Feb 09 00:00:00 CST 2024
> Thu Feb 08 19:57:33 CST 2024
> ```

You see that in all three examples the dates and times are the same as before, only the time zone abbreviation is now `CST` instead of `UTC`.

### Links

- [Java Best Practice for Date Manipulation/Storage for Geographically Diverse Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075780/java-best-practice-for-date-manipulation-storage-for-geographically-diverse-user)
- [`timestamp with time zone` in DB2](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/13?topic=values-timestamp)
- [ThreeTen Backport - Home](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)
- [Joda-Time - Home](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
- [`set session time zone` in DB2](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/13?topic=statements-set-session-time-zone)

Comment: I need to store the date in america/chicago timezone irrespective of the user location

Comment: I have no control over the database query

Comment: I am well aware that much of the information in the answer is not useful in your particular situation. I want the answer to be useful for other and future readers too, which is why I have included it anyway. I hope you can filter out what you need.

Comment: you are returning OffsetDateTime, I have no choice but to return always old Date object

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the database as well. is it impossible now?

Comment: Do we have option to put default timezone as CST instead of throwing the exception? if we don't pass the offset

Comment: Please ignore my last comment, if there is no offset we need to assume it's UTC and convert it to CST by subtracting 6 hours

Comment: is this the right way?   if (value.getTimezone() == DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED) {
                    dateTimeWithDeliberatelyWrongTimeZone = value.toGregorianCalendar()
                            .toZonedDateTime()
                            .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")) // Assume UTC time
                            .withZoneSameLocal(ZONE_ID); // Convert to CST
                }

Comment: I would leave out `.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"))` and just do as I did in the answer. Storing the date-time presumes UTC because it’s the default time zone of your server JVM. So what you really need is the default time zone, and my code already gave you that. So long as you know the server time zone will *always* be UTC, your extra code line does no harm since it makes no difference; but why rely on the server time zone being UTC when we are doing fine without this assumption? Up to you.

Comment: 2024-02-09T01:57:33.240 for this time its giving me Fri Feb 09 07:57:33 CST 2024 which is incorrect, I am in problem again its not changing the date

Comment: can you please update your code, if no time zone is given it should subtract 6 hours and give the date in cst, for example 2024-02-09T01:57:33.240 - 6 hours = 2024-02-08T19:57:33.240 CST

Comment: if (value.getTimezone() == DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED) {
                    return Date.from(value.toGregorianCalendar().
                            toZonedDateTime().withZoneSameInstant(UTC_ZONE_ID).withZoneSameInstant(CENTRAL_ZONE_ID).withZoneSameLocal(CENTRAL_ZONE_ID).toInstant());
                } I did like this, I will check your updated answer tommrow

Comment: What's the best way to test it using junit, my junit tests failes in local but passes in server, because my local date is EST and server is CST,       XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDateWithCSTOffset = getXmlDate("2024-02-09T01:57:33.240-06:00");
        Date date = fromXmlDate(xmlDateWithCSTOffset);
        Assertions.assertThat(date.toString()).isEqualTo("Fri Feb 09 01:57:33 CST 2024");
  private static XMLGregorianCalendar getXmlDate(String dateTime) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
        return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(dateTime);
    }

Comment: I know its because of toString, how can I assert it here?

Comment: @Carlene12War It’s an interesting question. It’s a new question, isn’t it? Consider posting it as such, with link back to your question here. In the JUnit test I would convert the `Date` to a `LocalDateTime` in the default time zone because then I know exactly what to expect.

Comment: In your JUnit test convert using `oldfashionedJavaUtilDateFromConversion .toInstant() .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()) .toLocalDateTime()`. Assert that the `LocalDateTime` is equal to something like `LocalDateTime.of(2024, Month.FEBRUARY, 9, 1, 57, 33, 240_000_000)` (the 240 000 000 being nanoseconds of second, so equal to 240 milliseconds).

Comment: @Carlene12War I had wanted to have a sample JUnit test run online (and not within my answer here since it doesn’t really belong), but I didn’t find an online compiler that offered that. [I have coded the main idea here,](https://rextester.com/EUK58983) but you will have to put it into a JUnit test yourself.

Answer (score 3):

### tl;dr

If handed a `XMLGregorianCalendar`, convert to modern class.

```java
myXmlGregCal
    .toGregorianCalendar()
    .toZonedDateTime()
    .withZoneSameInstant( 
        ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) 
    )
    .format (
        DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )
            .withLocale( Locale.GERMANY )
    )
```

If handed text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format with offset-from-UTC, parse as an `OffsetDateTime` object.

```java
OffsetDateTime
    .parse( "2024-02-09T01:57:33.240-06:00" ) 
    .atZoneSameInstant( 
        ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )
    )
    .format (
        DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )
            .withLocale( Locale.GERMANY )
    )
```

Convert a `XMLGregorianCalendar` to a `java.util.Date` by way of *java.time*:

```java
java.util.Date
    .from(
        myXmlGregCal
            .toGregorianCalendar()
            .toZonedDateTime()
            .toInstant()
    )
```

### Details

You are using terribly flawed date-time classes that are now legacy. Avoid `XMLGregorianCalendar`, `GregorianCalendar`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and both `Date` classes. They were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Among its many flaws is that `java.util.Date#toString` lies to you. That method interjects the JVM’s current default time zone while generating text to represent the UTC value of the object.

When handed a [`XMLGregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html) object, immediately convert to its modern replacement, [`java.time.ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) by way of [`java.util.GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myXmlGregCal.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime() ;
```

If you want to adjust that moment to be seen in a different time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to produce another `ZonedDateTime`. The *java.time* classes are [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), so you get a new object rather than changing the original.

```
ZoneId zTokyo = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtTokyo = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( zTokyo ) ;
```

Generate localized text.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = zdtTokyo.format( f ) ;
```

If you need to represent the moment in a `ZonedDateTime` as a `java.util.Date` to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, extract an `Instant`. Pass that to `java.util.Date.from`. Both `Instant` and `java.util.Date` represent a point on the timeline as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. The legacy class resolves to milliseconds while the modern class resolves to nanoseconds.

Comment: *When **handed** a XMLGregorianCalendar object...* Yes, but that's why I asked why one is being *used* here. It's being instantiated as part of the code and not with a zoned datetime value but an offset datetime value. The 'ur datum' is an offset datetime *string*.

Comment: Is this correct? public static Date convertDate2(XMLGregorianCalendar myXmlGregCal) {
        ZonedDateTime zdt = myXmlGregCal.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime() ;
        ZoneId zTokyo = ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" ) ;
        ZonedDateTime zdtTokyo = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( zTokyo ) ;
        Locale locale = Locale.US ;
        DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( locale ) ;
         return Date.from(zdtTokyo.toInstant());
    }

Comment: @saurabhkumar Definitely should not be using `LocalDateTime` in there. That class strips away any notion of time zone and offset, so you are needlessly discarding valuable information.

Comment: You shared me avoiding the use of both `Date` classes. Is `Date` required to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*? If so, which `Date` class, `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: Yes I can't use java.time

Comment: java.util.Date I am using

Comment: Please define your domain requirement as an *interface method* and we can code to that

Comment: @saurabhkumar You’ve really been jumping all around a bunch of classes and various formats of text. Simply tell us, what is your input, and what is your desired output?

Comment: @BasilBourque I am not sure if I can explain my problem in the right way, the function in my original question convertDate(XMLGregorianCalendar value) have to return a java.util.date I can't use any other class except XMLGregorianCalendar, I am passing this date 2024-02-09T01:57:33.240-06:00 but for some reason its saving in UTC format in db by adding 6 hours to original time. I need to save it in CST format.

Comment: Which RDBMS and what column type? And btw that is exactly what you should be doing at the server - storing the data in universal format. That's the U in UTC. That's the *model*. The *view* can be in any timezone you want

Comment: @g00se I have IBM db2 database, and I need to always store in america/chicago timezone,

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConstants;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.util.*;

import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConstants;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConstants;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.ZoneId;

import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConstants;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

public class Demo {



    public static final ZoneId ZONE_ID = ZoneId.of("America/Chicago");
    public static Date convertDate2(XMLGregorianCalendar myXmlGregCal) {
        ZonedDateTime zdt = myXmlGregCal.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime();
        ZoneId zChicago = ZoneId.of("America/Chicago");
        ZonedDateTime zdtChicago = zdt.withZoneSameInstant(zChicago);
        Locale locale = Locale.US;
        DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.FULL).withLocale(locale);
        String output = zdtChicago.format(f);

        // Parse the output string to LocalDateTime
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(output, f);

        // Convert LocalDateTime to Date
        Instant instant = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
        return Date.from(instant);
    }

    public static Date convertDate(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            if (value.getXMLSchemaType() == DatatypeConstants.DATE) {
                return value.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
            } else {
                LocalDateTime localDateTime = value.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime().withZoneSameInstant(ZONE_ID).toLocalDateTime();
                return Timestamp.valueOf(localDateTime);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Parse the XML date string into XMLGregorianCalendar
            XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2024-02-09T01:57:33.240-06:00");
            // Convert XMLGregorianCalendar to Date
            Date date = convertDate(xmlDate);
            // Print the result
          //  System.out.println("Date: " + date);
            System.out.println(convertDate2(xmlDate));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are seldom helpful. It’s from the explanations we all learn. I have not understood what your code is trying to tell us.

Comment: @Anonymous - Of course, the OP posted that 'answer' ;)

Comment: I ran your code. Output was `Fri Feb 09 01:57:33 CET 202`. CET is for Central European Time, the standard time in my time zone. It’s 7 hours ahead of North American Central Standard Time, so even though the time looks right, the `Date` object is wrong by 7 hours. I you run the code on a server with UTC as default time zone, the result will be wrong by "only" 6 hours.

Comment: it's wrong? What's wrong here in my code?

Comment: I haven’t taken the time to understand all of your code, and when you are giving me no explanation, I don’t think I should. I just observed that it was giving the wrong result when I ran it. Yes, the code is wrong.